# JQuery show/hide gives weird results

Tags: javascript, jquery

Im having some weird issues with javascript I can't really resolve.
I have three html input boxes with a small js file to show or hide the second and third one depending on what is picked in the first box. I'm using these functions:

```
$('#maintype').on('change', function() {
  if (this.value == '1') {
    $("#fries").show();
  } else {
    $("#fries").hide();
  }
});
```

The problem im running to is that the second dropdown is not shown when I highlight "fries". The third input box is never shown. I've tried all sorts of solutions, but I just can't figure out why.

I put my code on [github](https://github.com/ptrcksc/tmp)

Anyone that can give me some insight on where I am going wrong? Is there maybe another, simpler way to get this done?

Comment: Do you think you can place your html in the question so we may be able to take a look at it as while. Linking to a github repo usually isn't recommended.

Comment: why do you have 2 different document.ready and 5 `$(#maintype).on(change` ?

Comment: Would be nice if you could provide a minimal executable code which reproduces your problem. Digging into some github repo isn't what SO is for.

Comment: Oh sorry, I figured this'd be the easiest way to share multiple files. The issue is in the JS file, figured I'd just share everything to make it easier to spot the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two issues:

> The problem im running to is that the second dropdown is not shown when I highlight "fries"

Your check for fries is wrong, you have:

```
if ( this.value == '1') {
  $("#fries").show();
} else {
  $("#fries").hide();
}
```

but the check should be for '6' since that is the value you assigned to it in your #maintype select.

The other issue:

> The third input box is never shown.

You assigned the different IDs (eg. #fries, #icecream, etc.) to the `<div>` and not to the `<select>`.

You should also not have several elements with the same id or name (ie. #selectlist) in your case this will be solved when you fix the second issue.

Comment: Is it possible to have it thought? I generate the lists from a database with php.

Answer (score 0):

There is no handler for `<option value="6">fries</option>` , i mean there is no `if ( this.value == '6')` type line in your javascript code. I added below lines in your js file and it worked.

```
 $('#maintype').on('change', function() {
      if ( this.value == '6')
      //.....................^.......
      {
        $("#fries").show();
      }
      else
      {
        $("#fries").hide();
      }
    });
```

Demo : https://jsfiddle.net/gd548j0g/

Answer (score 0):

In your `#maintype` `select`, fries has a value of '6'. But in your change handler, you are looking for a value of `1`. In fact, there is no value in the select that has a value of `1`. Hence, the `fries` select box is never shown. Either change your handler to look for the id of `6`:

```
  $('#maintype').on('change', function() {
    if ( this.value == '6') {
      $("#fries").show();
    } else {
      $("#fries").hide();
    }
  });
```

Or change your `option` value for fries to `1`:

```
        <select class="select" id="maintype" name="maintype">
          <option value=""></option>
          <option value="3">filler</option>
          <option value="161">Icecreams</option>
          <option value="1">fries</option>
          <option value="7">Others</option>
          <option value="162">burgers</option>
          <option value="163">drinks</option>
        </select>
```

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/mspinks/vnofjobu/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<select class="select" id="maintype" name="maintype">
        <option value=""></option>
        <option value="3">filler</option>
        <option value="161">Icecreams</option>
        <option value="6">fries</option>
        <option value="7">Others</option>
        <option value="162">burgers</option>
        <option value="163">drinks</option>

        </select>

$('#maintype').on('change', function() {
if ( this.value == 6)
{
$("#fries").show();
}
else
{
$("#fries").hide();
}
```

be careful with the values that you assign to the options
your value of fries is 6, not 1

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your code in Git, you can achieve your output with below code in your showhide.js file.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#maintype').on('change', function() {
        $('input[type="text"]').hide(); //Hides all input with type Text, better if we do this using class
        var id = '#' + this.value;
        $(id).show(); //Show input with id which you have returned with this.value
    });
});
```